# The reading distance limit on passive RFID

Tags: wireless, rfid

It appears that nearly all "passive RFID" tag-reader combinations have around a 5-10cm specification for reading distance.

But I am interested in approx. 20 cm reading distance.

I am assuming one of these is the right approach to follow, but I'm not sure which:

- Perhaps the 5-10 cm range is a constraint of the passive RFID technology itself, and I should look into other technologies?
- Or is it that there exist variants within the passive RFID technology (and the frequency band within which they operate)?
- Or should I look into different kinds of tags specifically (I highly doubt this is the case since they do after all transmit upon being energized by the reader)?
- Or should I consider adding a specific external antenna to my RFID reader?

*Note:* I am aware of "Active RFID", but given its battery requirement on the tags, this is not ideal for my experiment.

Comment: They make tags with a higher range than that, maybe just not in the size you're looking for?  http://www.omni-id.com/products/RFID_tags-ultra.php  100 feet.

Comment: This guy does 9.8 meters http://www.gaorfidassettracking.com/RFID_Asset_Tracking_News/index.php?view=item&type=1&nid=11

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: Certainly not that big a size! (And that much range is not necessary even; just need about 20 cm)

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: Nevertheless, several meters with passive tags is very fascinating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, ISO 15693-compatible tags work fine at that sort of range (assuming that the reader antenna is properly tuned and emits a powerful enough field). For example NXP ICODE SLI-family tags are generally available online and are usually reasonably priced.